# SSRS Parameter Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I am trying to filter data using a text field, However when I specify the available Values to the dataset and field that I am using I recieve this error.

[image]

If I remove the Available values, The report runs fine.

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012, with SSRS addon.

Answer (score 1):

The available values can't be populated from the same data source that they are being applied to.

Create a separate data source for your available values and make sure they can populate without user interaction - without their own parameters in other words.

Comment: I have tried this already, the issue is that If I apply 2 dataset, the color doesnt show unless it specified

Comment: I don't understand. The color doesn't show where? Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: So I have created 2 dataset 1 I have added to the table, the second I use for parameters, This now returns the correct information, however the color field is always blank if color parameter is null, as soon as i specify it populates.

Comment: So the report loads, there's a column called color, which is blank, then  you specify a color from the parameters list, hit the view button, and the color column now populates. But you want the color column to populate when the report loads initially, before a color selection is made. Is that correct?

Comment: There must be rows in the database that have blank color values then. I would need to see your query, but its either returning everything, ordered by color, with rows that have no color showing up first, or its pulling only rows that have no color. Post your query above in your original question, but also, right click on the parameter in report builder and check the parameter details - is it set to accept null values?

Comment: Ignore the part about report builder - it looks like your doing this all through visual studio. Still, we'll need to know if your query is set up to accept null parameters.

Comment: Yes the color Parameter is set to allow Null

Comment: It sounds like its doing what it should do. Depending on how your query is set up, it will either pull all rows that have a null color, as it should since no color has been passed, or your query is using ISNULL, in which case it is bringing back everything regardless of its color. You can specify a default value or values to load some specific colors on load. You can do that useing ISNULL in your query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53821/discussion-between-david-murray-and-tintyethan)

Answer (score 0):

Get the distinct colors list on additional data-set and set it up as default value for your color parameter.
Remember that order of parameters is also important.